# CAsyncSocket receive() return value

Tags: c++, mfc, winsock

So, the documentation say :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/ct7d990b(v=VS.80).aspx

"Receive returns the number of bytes received. If the connection has been closed, it returns 0."

Given the fact the function is not blocking what if there is just no data?

How can one determine if it returned 0 because there is no data or because it disconnected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function would never return 0 if there is no data, Instead, it would return `SOCKET_ERROR` with `GetLastError() == WSAEWOULDBLOCK`.

Comment: i was meaning if there is no data because none arrived yet, unless you mean in that case the socket will return SOCKET_ERROR even if there is no error

Comment: Yes. If you are using Asynchronous socket, `GetLastError() == WSAEWOULDBLOCK` is not really an error.